# addSubview to super.superView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I have

mainView_a->ScrollView_b->ScrollView_c->View_d->Button

and after Button touchUpInside I need to addSubView to ScrollView_b
is it possigle????

i tried [super.super addSubview:myNewView];

```
-(IBAction)showPhotoGallery:(id) sender
{
    UIScrollView *photoGalleryScV = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 800)];
    photoGalleryScV.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [super.super addSubview:photoGalleryScV];

    //[photoGalleryScV release];
}
```

it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

`super` is a keyword referring to the superclass of your class, not the superview.

Try

```
[self.superview.superview.superview addSubview:photoGalleryScV];
```

So:

- `self` is Button
- `self.superview` is view_d
- `self.superview.superview` is scrollview_c
- `self.superview.superview.superview` is scrollview_b

Though this seems a bit fragile, you might be better using the application delegate's main view or root controller and working down instead?

Answer (score 0):

`self` would not be a Button normally in that code. `self` would be a UIViewController. `sender` would be the UIButton. Therefore

```
[sender.superview.superview.superview addSubview:photoGalleryScV];
```

might work.

Better than working up or down would be to define an outlet in your view controller that points to ScrollView_b no matter how you rearrange it in your view structure. Connect it in interface builder (or in code in loadView if you prefer). Then

```
[self.scrollView_b addSubview:photoGalleryScV];
```